# MATLAB : using mkdir for making tree-like folder

Tags: matlab, tree, directory, mkdir

[image]

I want to make some tree-like folders

I made my code but I don't how I can use string

Below is my code

```
for i=1:10;


mkdir('C:\Users\kanje\Desktop\', ['s0' num2str(i) '_e01']);
mkdir('[C:\Users\kanje\Desktop\'s0' num2str(i) '_e01\']', convolution);  % here is the problem
mkdir('[C:\Users\kanje\Desktop\'s0' num2str(i) '_e01\']', unconvolution);

for ii=1:9;

mkdir('[C:\Users\kanje\Desktop\'s0' num2str(i) '_e01\convolution']', 'a01_s0' num2str(ii) '_e01');
mkdir('[C:\Users\kanje\Desktop\'s0' num2str(i) '_e01\unconvolution']', 'a01_s0' num2str(ii) '_e01');

end;

end;
```

Maybe I cannot use well about string

Explain:

a01_e01 to a10_e01 is the parent folder

Each a01_e01 ,..., a10_e01 have convolution & un-convolution folder as see

And the convolution & un-convolution folders have the a01_s01_e01 ,..., a01_s10_e01 folders

At last one parent folder should have a10_s01_e01 to a10_s10_e01 (it's not in this picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) command to construct the path names and [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to [format the strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html):

```
rootPath = fullfile( 'c:', 'Users', 'kanje', 'Desktop' );
for ai=1:10
    baseName = fullfile( rootPath, sprintf( 'a%02d_e01', ai ) );
    mkdir( baseName );
    for sub = {'convolution', 'unconvolution' }
        mkdir( fullfile( baseName, sub{1} ) );
        for si=1:10
            subName = fullfile( baseName, sub{1}, sprintf( 'a%02d_s%02d_e01', ai, si ) );
            mkdir( subName );
        end
    end
end
```